# Does PSD imply on average diagonal dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $N \times N$ positive semidefinite matrix.   This does not necessarily imply that $A$ is diagonally dominant.  But does it imply the following "average diagonal dominance" i.e.

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}A_{i,i}\ge \frac{2}{(N-1)N} \sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{i<j}A_{i,j}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: If true, it must be $\geq$ in the relation. $11^T$ as an example would require that.

Comment: Dimitar.  yes i will allow $\ge$

Comment: Just curious. What does it mean to have $(N+1)N$ as the denominator on the RHS? Obviously it is not the number of elements in the double summation (that would be $N(N-1)/2$).

Comment: user1551 should be N(N-1)/2.   you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are talking about real matrices. If so, the inequality is true. We only need to consider only the case where the RHS is nonnegative, because the LHS is always nonnegative. So, it suffices to prove the inequality that
$$
\frac1N\sum_i a_{ii} \ge \frac2{N(N-1)}\sum_j\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}\tag{1}
$$
when the RHS is nonnegative. In turn, it suffices to prove $(1)$ in general, regardless of whether the RHS is nonnegative or not.

Rewrite $(1)$ as $\operatorname{trace}(A)\ge u^TAu$, where $u$ is the unit vector $\frac1{\sqrt{N}}(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. Now the inequality obviously holds. In fact, when $A$ is PSD, we have $\operatorname{trace}(A)\ge \lambda_\max(A)\ge v^TAv$ for every unit vector $v$.